# What can I do if someone sitting nearby snores loudly in a library?

Tags: sound, sleeping

I was reading in a public library when someone started snoring. I thought a librarian would step in, but I cannot find one right now in this room.

There are about 30 readers in this room, but no one does anything to stop the snorer, and some of them even laugh. It has been lasting for about 5 minutes. I am just wondering if it is necessary/polite for me to go to his desk and wake him up, which would draw all 30 people's attention.

What can I do to silence the person without evoking unpleasant reactions? What if the librarian came in but did nothing to it?

Comment: Unpleasant reactions from the 30 wakeful readers or the snorer? How do you know the snorer will be displeased and not thankful? Gently shake their shoulder and move away. They may not even know who woke them :)

Comment: @WeatherVane From The snorer.

Answer (score 2):

Jokes aside, I don't think libraries have specific rules against snoring inside them.

As far as I can I tell, most rules are to prevent noise *made on purpose*, and unless one arrived to the library with the goal of sleeping there, it's human and expected that some just fall asleep during reading sometimes, and naturally they sometimes also snore.

So, it is indeed unlikely a librarian will come over and wake up the sleeping person.

This leaves it up to you, if the snoring really bothers you so much and prevent you from reading properly, the "task" of making a stop to the snoring falls on your own shoulders.

One way, without making noise yourself to wake the sleeping person up, is to gently shake their shoulders, as Weather Vane [also said in a comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/what-can-i-do-if-someone-sitting-nearby-snores-loudly-in-a-library#comment39765_27603) and go away without waiting for them to wake up.

You can do it even without the others seeing it, so it should not cause any commotion or curious looks.

Done gently enough (but also firmly enough to have the desired effect of waking up the person), the sleeper might not even realize what happened, think they woke up naturally, and resume their actual activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to do.

1. If you can, move to a different section of the library. This might be the quickest solution.
2. Libraries often have disposable earplugs. Go and ask for a pair.
3. You can make a sudden noise in your seat or just cough. This can be enough to nudge the person awake without drawing attention.
4. Walk over to the person and politely whisper that the sound is disturbing.
5. If you can't find the librarian you initially saw, try locating another one in a different section. Briefly explain the situation and see if they can help.